# increase swagger requestTimeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, swagger-ui, netflix-zuul

is there anyway that can help me increase the timeout of the swagger request that i issue to my RestAPI using " Try it out" of swagger ?

i roamed the internet and disn't find something usefull, and i tried to add things to my yml conf files, but i didn't know what to write

i expected to find something like this maybe :

```
swagger.timeout=5000
```

i have a spring boot application using swagger in order to test my webservices in a restController. i have a treatement that takes about 30 seconds, the thing that makes swagger throw a 500 timeout error for me.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Swagger registers its endpoints as normal Spring controllers so use the underlying web container to serve its traffic.

Try to increase the global connection timeout:

```
server.connection-timeout=120000
```

> Time that connectors wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default is used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (that is, an infinite) timeout.

Comment: this is deprecated

Comment: @ShankPossible - find an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding this to ZUUL's (API Gateway)

```
ribbon:
ReadTimeout: 120000
ConnectTimeout: 120000
```